# How to query data from MapImageLayer? ArcGIs for android 100.x

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-android-api

I want to be able to query data from MapImageLayer
But I can't seem to find relevant tutorials and APIs

FeatureLayer has such a method

```
public ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> selectFeaturesAsync​(QueryParameters query, FeatureLayer.SelectionMode selectionMode)
```

then get graphic(highlight) and attributes

so how to do it.

> In javascript, I use sublayer. creatureLayer to achieve the goal
> But there is no such method in android. Thank you for your watching and answer

I try to use **MapImageLayer.getTables()**

Get **ServiceFeatureTable** from it to use **queryFeaturesAsync()**

But **getTables().size=0**

Answer (score 0):

I still can't use MapImageLayer to query directly
But use the url of the sublayer to create a ServiceFeatureTable to query
At present, relevant data can be queried

MapImageLayer is `http://host/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer`

ServiceFeatureTable is `http://host/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/id`

after get some Tables

```java
QueryParameters parameters = new QueryParameters();
parameters.setGeometry(selectBuffer.getGeometry());
parameters.setOutSpatialReference(SpatialReferences.getWebMercator());
parameters.setReturnGeometry(true);
parameters.setSpatialRelationship(QueryParameters.SpatialRelationship.INTERSECTS);
for(ServiceFeatureTable table : layerList){    ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> listenableFuture = table.queryFeaturesAsync(parameters);
    listenableFuture.addDoneListener(() -> {
        try {
            FeatureQueryResult queryResult = listenableFuture.get();
            for(Feature feature:queryResult){
                //TODO
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

It is worth reminding that when using setSpatialRelationship, it is better to set the parameter to INTERSECTS
At present, I am still trying to display the acquired features on the map, using the highlighted method
Still looking forward to someone's answer